# Angular Syntax Highlighter in Visual Studio HTML files

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

Sometimes a lot of angular and code appears  in the html file. With a highlighter it would be easier to see what we have in the file,for both code and directives.

Are there any tools with such a syntax highlight ability?

Comment: I have a similar question. I do have syntax highlighting in the HTML for angular but it does not work when there is a `data` prefix tag present. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38659594/visual-studio-2015-html-angular-syntax-highlight, maybe that can help you get a start.

Comment: Were there not a bounty on the question, I would vote this question as off topic, as it is clearly a request for a tool.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,  there is no opportunity to add angular IntelliSense to HTML in the Visual Studio, at least now.

As an alternative answer for your question, I would suggest trying another Microsoft product named - [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/?utm_expid=101350005-28.R1T8FshdTBWEfZjY0s7XKQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.ua%2F). It has out of box support of what you are looking for (Angular HTML IntelliSense).

It supports [C#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp), and most of the languages currently used in web development. In case you miss anything, you always can upgrade it with a help of [Extensions market](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode).