# Visual Studio 2015 - HTML - Angular Syntax Highlight

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

We use angular heavily in our html pages and currently attributes that start with `ng-` get a different fore color applied to content inside the attribute. This is also the case with values inside an angular expression `{{expression}}`. This makes reading larger HTML documents easier on the eye especially when working with the Angular parts.

However as soon as you add the `data-` prefix to an angular tag like changing `ng-if` to `data-ng-if` the highlighting is lost/removed. So my question is how can I get the `.html` and `.cshtml` text editor to apply collor formatting to my html attributes that start with `data-ng-`?

[image: Syntax highlight example]

---

### What I have tried so far

I started with trying to find where I could find the recognition of the `ng-` attribute prefix and figured I could edit it from there but this is where I got stuck.

*Note that between each attempt to solve this issue I have restarted Visual Studio. If there is something else I should do/try as well to ensure that a cache somewhere is refreshed please let me know, maybe I solved the issue but am not seeing results because of that.*

#### Color Theme Editor

I recently discovered a new extension for Visual Studio called [Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6f4b51b6-5c6b-4a81-9cb5-f2daa560430b). Using color matching I found that the `ng-` attributes had the color applied in the theme using `Text Editor -> HTML Client Template Value`. Trying to find this I searched the Options in VS and came across `Options -> Text Editor -> HTML (Web Forms) -> Formatting -> Tag Specific Options...` but I could not find anything specific to the Angular attributes here.

#### Other Extensions

I am now thinking maybe its actually a part of an extension and not baked into Visual Studio. These are the relevant extensions I have installed:

- Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools
- Microsoft ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools
- Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library and JavaScript

I can not find any thing inside of VS where I can edit settings for any of this but I could be looking in the wrong place.

#### Web Tools Extension

I found a folder named `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Schemas\1033\HTML` and have edited the file `SchemaCatalog.xml` to include a new element *which is a copy of the angular element*.

```
 <schema File="angularData.xsd" FriendlyName="AngularDataJS" Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/angular" IsSupplemental="true" CustomPrefix="data-ng-" />
```

I then created a copy of the `angular.xsd` file with the name `angularData.xsd` and did a find/replace on `ng-` with `data-ng-`. In the `SchemaCatalog.xml` I ordered the line items so that the new record was before records that had the `CustomPrefix="data-"`. This also seemed to not have any effect.

#### XSD files

I have also tried looking in the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html` and the `.xsd` files but here I also could not find anything with wording relating to angular or `ng-` as prefix.

Answer (score 2):

What I was able to find out is that this color for ng-XXX attribute can be modified in Font&Colors / HTML Client Template Value (in Display Items panel). My guess is that there is somewhere client template for Angular installed. One which tells VS that `ng-` prefix is Angular tag making it "client template" tag. I was able to find this file:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Schemas\1033\HTML\angular.xsd

Some names are listed there but I am not sure if adding others with `data-ng-` prefix will apply this color. Also I found so far nothing about where those client templates stored and how to eventually manage them.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried ReSharper with AngularJS plugins   https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/02/28/angularjs-support-for-resharper/

AngularJS plugins

https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/AngularJS/

Comment: I am not looking to install a r# plugin to make this work.

Comment: this will give you just intellsense but will not change coloring for data-ng statements. I am personally looking for solution too.